# Grunt task exits with Bus Error: 10

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, jshint, grunt-contrib-watch

I am using the following JSHint Grunt task, which is passing okay:

```
jshint: {
            options: {
                ignores: ['js/characters/**/*.js','js/libs/**/*.js','js/text.js','js/video.js'],
                predef: ['define', 'require'],
                reporter: require('jshint-stylish'),

                curly: true,
                eqnull: true,
                eqeqeq: true,
                undef: false,




            },
            all: ['js/**/*.js'],



        }
```

I am trying to configure it to work within a watch task:

```
watch: {

            scripts: {
               files: ['<%= jshint.all %>'],
             ignores: ['js/characters/**/*.js','js/libs/**/*.js','js/text.js','js/video.js'],
               tasks: ['jshint']
           },
            css: {
                files: ['**/*.sass'],
                tasks: ['compass'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true,
                }
            }
        }
```

but every time I change a JS file, the watch exits with `Bus error: 10`

Comment: Well a bus error is pretty much a Node runtime bug.

Comment: Okay, so this isn't something I am doing? hmmm. Can't seem to find anyone else with the issue

Comment: Maybe this? https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/6251

Comment: Yup that sure looks like it.

Comment: Best answer my own question then!! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Upgrading to Node 0.10.22 fixed this issue.